# Group the geom_lines by years

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I would like to plot a geom_line plot with the lines divided by years of the variable date, that goes from 01/04/2018 to 31/03/2021, and then use weekly breaks from Jan-Dec with the labels appearing only every three weeks (e.g., "1-7 Jan", "22-28 Jan", "12-18Feb", and so on). My first problem, was precisely grouping the lines into groups. I have tried:

```
df %>%
ggplot(aes(x=date, y=n, group = year(date), colour = year(date)))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", breaks = seq.Date(ymd("2018-04-01"),ymd("2021-03-31"), by = "month"))
```

However, all the years still appear in the X axis.

I have also tried to change the breaks, create a variable with the different years and use different data frames for each year:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=a2018, aes(x=date, y=n))+
  geom_line(data=b2019, aes(x=date, y=n))+
  geom_line(data=c2020, aes(x=date, y=n))+
  geom_line(data=d2021, aes(x=date, y=n))
```

I feel like I am probably missing/doing something silly but it is taking me a while to solve it.

Comment: OP, can you share a reproducible example with some data?  The data can be from a built-in dataset or your own data.  If sharing your own data, please share by pasting the code output via `dput(df)` or a sample of your dataframe (ex. `dput(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 40),])`).

Answer (score 0):

Extract a separate `year` column using `lubridate::year()`, then change all `date`s to the same `year` using `lubridate::"year<-"()`. Use `minor_breaks` to set breaks every week and `breaks` to label every third week. (You could also use `date_minor_breaks = "1 week", date_breaks = "3 weeks"` if you're not fussy about the first tick being January 1).

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

df$year <- factor(year(df$date))
year(df$date) <- 2020 # use a leap year if any of `date` is 3/29

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = n, group = year, colour = year)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%d %b", 
    breaks = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"), ymd("2020-12-31"), by = "3 weeks"),
    minor_breaks = seq(ymd("2020-01-01") - 21, ymd("2020-12-31") + 21, by = "1 week")
  )
```

[image]

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(13)

df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("2018-04-01"), ymd("2021-03-31"), by = "day"),
  n = purrr::accumulate(round(rnorm(1095, sd = 10)), `+`, .init = 250)
)
```